# storage.googleapis.com I get "Your connection is not private"

Tags: mobile, google-cloud-platform, connection, google-cloud-storage, mobile-data

I have a strange error. When I try to load a public blob from Google Cloud Storage in a browser,  I get the error "Your connection is not private".

And more strange, when I go to see the certificate, it is emmited to "*.JUEGOILEGAL.ES". For example https://storage.googleapis.com/ysi_production/newsletter-assets/chica_lupa.png

[image]

When I'm connected to wifi, there is no problem, but when I'm connected to mobile data, the error appears. I'm trying with some different network operators from Spain, and with some it happens, and others not. For example, with some [MásMóvil](https://www.masmovil.es/) and [Pepephone](https://www.pepephone.com/) it happens, with [Movistar](https://www.movistar.es/) not.

What happens?

Comment: Did you try to play with IPv4 and IPv6 network configuration? I already had this issue with some websites.

Comment: Yes @guillaumeblaquiere and nothing happens. It's something that occurs to different terminals and different network operators.

Comment: Do you have extension, plugin or proxy that could interfere in the communication?

Comment: Nothing special

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try the following things:

- Open the link in [Incognito mode](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464)
- [Clear browser cache and cookies](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)
- Temporarily turn off your antivirus, just to check if there an issue there
- Change DNS settings. For example to the ones provided by Google (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4)